# To display range of date from start date and end_date in select statement of MYSQL

Tags: mysql

select * from transactional_detail;

```
transaction_id  product_id  customer_id start_date  end_date
1               1           1           30-12-2014  01-01-2015
```

Need output in the format given below:

```
transaction_id  product_id  customer_id date
1               1           1           30-12-2014
1               1           1           31-12-2014
1               1           1           01-01-2015
```

Kindly provide a SQL query in MYSQL.

Regards,
Arun

Comment: How about you try something first?

Comment: Dates in relational databases adhere to a specific format. This isn't it.

Comment: function or procedure wouldn't provide a list of values for given a date range.@Strawberry this format is a copy paste from excel

Comment: SELECT calendar.datefield AS DATE, count(td.product_id) AS total_product FROM transaction_detail td RIGHT JOIN calendar ON (calendar.datefield = (td.start_date) left join product_detail pd on (pd.product_id = td.product_id)left join product_type pt on (pt.product_type_id = pd.product_type_id) GROUP BY DATE ; union same     query with end_date in the join condition. I want to fetch the dates  in between the range.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to return the specified resultset, you need a row source that can be joined to the table, to generate "duplicate" rows.

One approach is to create and populate a calendar type table with a list of all possible dates you want to return:

```
CREATE TABLE cal (dt DATE NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY) ENGINE=InnoDB;
INSERT INTO cal (dt) VALUES ('2010-01-01');
INSERT INTO cal (dt) SELECT dt + INTERVAL 1 DAY FROM cal ORDER BY dt;
INSERT INTO cal (dt) SELECT dt + INTERVAL 2 DAY FROM cal ORDER BY dt;
INSERT INTO cal (dt) SELECT dt + INTERVAL 4 DAY FROM cal ORDER BY dt;
INSERT INTO cal (dt) SELECT dt + INTERVAL 8 DAY FROM cal ORDER BY dt;
INSERT INTO cal (dt) SELECT dt + INTERVAL 16 DAY FROM cal ORDER BY dt;
INSERT INTO cal (dt) SELECT dt + INTERVAL 32 DAY FROM cal ORDER BY dt;
INSERT INTO cal (dt) SELECT dt + INTERVAL 64 DAY FROM cal ORDER BY dt;
INSERT INTO cal (dt) SELECT dt + INTERVAL 128 DAY FROM cal ORDER BY dt;
INSERT INTO cal (dt) SELECT dt + INTERVAL 256 DAY FROM cal ORDER BY dt;
INSERT INTO cal (dt) SELECT dt + INTERVAL 512 DAY FROM cal ORDER BY dt;
INSERT INTO cal (dt) SELECT dt + INTERVAL 1024 DAY FROM cal ORDER BY dt;
INSERT INTO cal (dt) SELECT dt + INTERVAL 2048 DAY FROM cal ORDER BY dt;
INSERT INTO cal (dt) SELECT dt + INTERVAL 4096 DAY FROM cal ORDER BY dt;
```

---

Then, reference that table in join operation, to get all the `dt` values that "match".

Assuming that `start_date` and `end_date` columns are DATE datatype:

```
SELECT t.transaction_id
     , t.product_id
     , t.customer_id
     , c.dt
  FROM transactional_detail t
  JOIN cal c
    ON c.dt >= t.start_date
   AND c.dt <= t.end_date
 ORDER
    BY t.transaction_id
     , t.product_id
     , t.customer_id
     , c.dt
```

If `start_date` and `end_date` are VARCHAR rather than DATE (which would be a really bad design choice), you'd need to cast those to DATE datatype to get a date comparison semantics, e.g.

```
    ON c.dt >= STR_TO_DATE(t.start_date,'%d-%m-%Y')
   AND c.dt <= STR_TO_DATE(t.end_date,'%d-%m-%Y')
```

Comment: That works perfectly ,thanks @spencer7593. I used a procedure to populate the cal table DELIMITER $$
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `fill_calendar`(start_date DATE, end_date DATE)
BEGIN
  DECLARE crt_date DATE;
  SET crt_date=start_date;
  WHILE crt_date < end_date DO
    INSERT INTO calendar VALUES(crt_date);
    SET crt_date = ADDDATE(crt_date, INTERVAL 1 DAY);
  END WHILE;

END$$
DELIMITER ;

Answer (score 0):

```
$startDate = date("d-m-Y",strtotime($row['start_date']));
```

Comment: this looks php where mysql was asked...